# How does the Docker build command limit row count for the image's stdout? (see my gif pls)

Tags: macos, docker, stdout

[docker build process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp0fc.gif)

I read that `docker build` is using some templates written in Go but I'm trying to achieve this for a `yarn add` or `start` from a python script. Their outputs are too verbose and I don't want to see the whole thing. I'm very familiar with Jinja.

I'm running MacOS Big Sur 11.4
& Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350

Comment: The output of my `docker build` looks very very different, so it would help if you edit the question and add OS/distro and the docker version you are using.

Comment: thanks, just did that.

Comment: Looking at the [options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/), there's now a `--progress` option that I don't see on my `docker` (version 18 via homebrew). So first thing I'd try is `--progress plain`. Second thing I'd try is `--quiet`.